# Как изменить значения определённых полей, содержащихся в классе

Tags: c#

Пишу класс, отвечающий за регулирование работы настроек программы. 
Мне нужно иметь метод, который всем свойствам задаст значение по умолчанию.
Зашёл в тупик, что-то не знаю, как добить вопрос. Код:

```
class Options
{
    bool StartWithWindowsType;
    string Name;
    public string Value
    {
       // ...
    }

    string DefaultValue;

    protected Options(string name,  string def_value, bool start_with_windows=false)
    {
        Name = name;
        DefaultValue = def_value;
        StartWithWindowsType = start_with_windows;
    }

    public static Options StartWithWindows;

    // вызывается извне, инициализируем все опции
    public static void Init()
    {
       StartWithWindows = new Options("StartWithWindows", "1", true);
    }       

    // всем полям класса Options задать значение value = значению по умолчанию
    public static void AllToDefault()
    {
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Options).GetFields();

        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo opt in fields)
            ???
    }
```

Если использовать дженерик, сталкиваюсь с проблемой.
Мне нужно в аксессоре get для поля задать получение значения из реестра, пишу так:

```
T Value
{
    get
    {
        var res = Reg.Read(Name);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
        {
            return DefaultValue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Value.GetType() == typeof(int))
                return Convert.ToInt32(res);

            if (Value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
                return Convert.ToBoolean(res);
        }
    }
    set
    {
        // ...
    }
```

`return Convert.ToInt32(res);` - проблема - как указать что нужно вернуть переменную типа `T`

Comment: Господи, а зачем рефлексия? Присвоить всем полям значение уже слишком сложно?

Comment: ради опыта @VladD

Comment: Окей, в таком случае хорошо. Я напишу, если никто не успеет раньше. Но всё же такое решение не стоит применять в реальной жизни без веских причин (а лень таковой не является).

Comment: И ещё одна ремарка. Настройка -- это имя + значение, либо имя + значение + дефолтное значение. Как по мне -- ну никак не вяжется сюда имя + дефолтное значение + стартовать при запуске ОС. Что-то не так спроектировано. Давайте ещё раз. Есть одна настройка, есть набор настроек. Они все string только или могут быть ещё Int, bool и так далее?

Comment: @AK я хотел сделать по-умному, чтобы тип поля Value для экземпляра настройки определялся при создании экземпляра. Не осилил эту тему и решил сделать Value просто типа string, а там уж приводить к чему надо. С настройкой "стартовать при запуске ОС" логика остаётся та же, просто если ДА - записываем в реестр нужную строку, если нет - стираем

Answer (score 4):

Давайте сначала выясним, как это можно сделать технически.

Для начала, как получить список всех полей? У нас есть метод `Type.GetFields()`, но какой наш тип? `typeof(Options)` может и не быть нашим *настоящим* типом, вдруг мы произвели класс-потомок? Правильный метод получения типа — метод `GetType()`.

Далее, какие поля мы хотим получить? Нам нужны как открытые (`public`, так и закрытые `private`) поля: обычно поля скрывают, а открывают свойства. Кроме того, нам нужны поля экземпляра, но не статические поля. Но метод `GetFields` возвращает лишь открытые поля для классов-предков, поэтому нам придётся итерировать по всем базовым типам.

Если мы уж итерируем по всем типам, нам не нужно получать унаследованные поля, поэтому скормим в `GetFields` модификатор `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`.

Это приводит к такому коду:

```
// цикл по типу и всем базовым типам
for (Type type = GetType(); type != null; type = type.BaseType)
{
    foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                         BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Что внутри цикла? Нам нужно присвоить значение по умолчанию. Если это значение `default(T)` данного типа, то [можно получить его](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490274/276994) при помощи следующего кода:

```
Type fieldType = field.FieldType;
object defaultValue = fieldType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(fieldType) : null;
```

Это проверяет, является ли наш типа значимым или ссылочным типом. Для ссылочного типа `default`-значение есть `null`, а значимый тип имеет конструктор по умолчанию.

Получается:

```
for (Type type = GetType(); type != null; type = type.BaseType)
{
    foreach (var field in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                         BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        Type fieldType = field.FieldType;
        object defaultValue = fieldType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(fieldType) :
                                                      null;
        field.SetValue(this, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Если же вы храните default-значение в одном из полей, и отличаете по имени, то непонятно, что делать, если тип поля и тип default-значения различаются. Для вашего случая можно написать просто:

```
field.SetValue(this, defaultValue);
```

а если вы хотите избежать присваивания default-значения самому себе, то надо проверить его имя и принадлежность (т. к. может быть много полей с одинаковым именем):

```
if (field.Name == "defaultValue" && type == typeof(Options))
    continue;
field.SetValue(this, defaultValue);
```

---

Теперь о проблемах.

Для начала, поля. Вы присваиваете значения полям, минуя свойства. Это не вполне правильно, ведь свойства при присвоении могут выполнять какую-нибудь логику, которую вы пропускаете при вашем подходе. (Эту проблему можно частично решить, работая со *свойствами* вместо полей, но если в вашем классе есть и поля, не укладывающиеся на свойства, проблем не избежать.)

Затем, значение по умолчанию. Это значение может и не быть хорошим начальным значением для *всех* полей. Если вы пользуетесь `default(T)`, то для строки правильным значением вполне может оказаться `""` или там `"(none)"`. Рефлексия это полностью нивелирует.

Далее, с рефлексией вы не сможете *отказаться* от обнуления какого-то из полей, разве что вам придётся вводить атрибуты, и заставлять пользователя прикреплять атрибуты к полям, влияющие на поведение обнуляющего метода. Это превратит невинную фичу в целый фреймворк.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что автор всё же хотел что-то на generic'ах:

```
void Main()
{
    var option1 = new Option<string>("City", "Moscow");
    var option2 = new Option<bool>("StartWithWindows", false);
    var option3 = new Option<int>("ThreadsCount", 10);

    option1.Set("Vologda");
    option2.Set(true);
    option3.Set(15);

    Console.WriteLine(option1.Get());
    Console.WriteLine(option2.Get());
    Console.WriteLine(option3.Get());
}

public class Option<T>
{
    public Option(string name, T defaultValue)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.Value = defaultValue;
    }

    public void Set(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }

    public T GetDefaultValue()
    {
        return this.DefaultValue;
    }        

    private string Name { get; set; }

    private T DefaultValue { get; set; }

    private T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(Option<T> value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

Вывод переменных сразу после объявления:

> Moscow
>
> False
>
> 10

и после установки:

> Vologda
>
> True
>
> 15

Или так, без значений по умолчанию:

```
public class Options
{
    public Option<string> BirthCity { get; set; }

    public Option<string> CurrentCity { get; set; }

    public Option<bool> StartWithWindows { get; set; }

    public Option<int> ThreadsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: гляньте пожалуйста мою правку к основному тексту вопроса